# How to pass child DOM nodes to react styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, styled-components

I would like to make a React component `MyWrapper` that allows for me to wrap other child HTML/components such as

```
<MyWrapper>
  <div>More code here</div>
</MyWrapper>
```

In the Angular world, this is called *transclusion*. I'm not as familiar with React so I'm not sure what to search for, or if it's even possible with Styled Components.

See the example below which stylizes a header title with colors and a typeface. Note how the content "Hello World, this is [..]" is hard-coded. Surely this component would be more useful and reusable if the inner HTML could be passed to the component and it could style any text this way.

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components#example

Comment: you may use hoc higher order component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `this.props.children`:

```
class MyWrapper extend React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Wrapper>{this.props.children}</Wrapper>;
  }
}
```

and then you can do:

```
<MyWrapper>
    <div>My code here</div>
</MyWrapper>
```